# installing R 3.3.2 in HOME directory in centos

Tags: r, centos, zlib

I am trying to  install R 3.3.2 on a server running centos 6. I have to install it in my Home directory on the server because i don't have the permissions anywhere else. I downloaded it using wget and then tar. But when I reach the point of "./configure" in order to run "make" afterwards it stops with an error.

checking if zlib version >= 1.2.5... no
checking whether zlib support suffices... configure: error: zlib library and headers are required

I installed zlib 1.2.8 and added its path to my bash_profile then tried to run the command ./configure for the R again but i got the same error. It seems that it still sees that I am using an old version of zlib (1.2.3) (The one that is already installed on the server). Have anyone had a similar issue or have any advices regarding this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you get if you do `which zlib`?

Answer (score 0):

> and added its path to my bash_profile

I am curious if you prepended or appended the path. In the latter case, configure will detect the old zlib.
In order to prepend, do like

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/zlib/inst/dir/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}